# Пунктуация при тексте с цитатой

Tags: прямая-речь, пунктуация

Часто бывает, что в тексте как бы цитата, но не прямая речь и не что-то подобное.  Как в этом случае действовать? Ставить ли кавычки и нужно ли что-то еще, вроде двоеточий, тире и запятых. Например:

> Хмурое "угу" было ему ответом.

Например, если герой повторяет за другим - это цитата и ее нужно ставить в кавычки или как?

> -- Ты же сказал "согласен".

В случаях, когда это не прямая цитата

> -- Ты же сказал, что согласен.

Больше примеров не придумалось, но общий принцип, я думаю, понятен - что делать, если в тексте как бы цитата, но не совсем, и вроде речь, но тоже не подходит под это определение, на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы всё правильно понимаете, и знаки поставлены верно. В таких случаях на помощь приходят кавычки или оформляется предложение с косвенной речью.

Выделяются кавычками:
*слова непривычные, малоупотребительные, на которые автор хочет обратить внимание: Петушков **"стрепенулся"**, а солдат вытянулся, пожелал ему **"здравья"** и вручил ему большой пакет, запечатанный казённой печатью (Т.);

слова из чужого текста, цитаты: Воспитанный на красивом языке бабушки и деда, я вначале не понимал такие соединения несоединимых слов, как **"ужасно смешно", "до смерти хочу есть", "страшно весело"**... (М.Г.)*   [Здесь](http://www.yaklass.ru/materiali/?mode=lesson&lsnid=554)